# how to migrate bash prompt \#/\! to zsh

Tags: zsh, prompt

My bash prompt currently starts with the following variables :

```
\#/\!
```

which means

```
\#   The command number of this command.

\!   The history number of this command.
```

So `\#` is specific to each terminal but the `\!` is relative the global history file.

In zsh, `%!` appears to be equivalent to bash `\#`.

**How do you translate bash `\!` in zsh ?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have the equivalent in zsh, but you can do the same thing by using a counter in `preexec`:

```
preexec() { psvar[1]=$((cctr++)) }
PS1='%1v/%! '
```

is more or less equivalent to `PS1='\#/\! '` in bash.